# Glass mapper is appending 'h' and 'w' on image tags source URL

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc

We upgraded glass mapper to v.4.0.9.60 from v 3.2.1.42. after upgrading URLs are being appended by h and w as height and width which is resulting into some improper image rendering. In previous version it was working fine.
If we remove h and w query strings from URL or replace with width and height, it renders fine, provided outputHeightWidth for image should be true.

It should be as -

[image]

But displaying as -

[image]

Everytime image source is as follows

```
<img src="imgsrc.jpg?h=47&w=70">
```

Please advise. How can we remove this from URL without triggering any script code?

Comment: how do you render images in your view? looks like your question is incomplete

Comment: Check out this blog post: http://www.glass.lu/Blog/ImageParameters.

Comment: @SitecoreClimber - We are using RenderImage glass mapper helper to render images in our view. During our analysis, we found out that these parameters (h, w, lang_code etc.) are getting appended to Image URL by GlassHtml.cs file which was not present earlier with version 3. Any idea how to opt out for this?

Comment: Thanks @BenGolden We've gone through this article. According to this article, Glass mapper appends 'w' and 'h' parameters to the Image Src itself with version 4 which is creating problem - image is getting distorted with black background color. If we remove these parameter or replace 'w' with 'width' (as in Glass mapper v3) in the Image Src then it works fine. I'm unable to find any option to opt out for these parameters from getting appended.